# Easy save in myData.lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I know that I can use

```
if mydata.settings.something >= 1 then
something
```

But can I save data also in one line? I tried things like this

```
mydata.settings.something = 1
_G.something = 1
_G.mydata.settings.something = 1
```

and it doesn't work, can someone tell me if there is a short function to save data?

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*? I also don't see how your first snippet of code saves anything.

Comment: I mean that i don't know how to do this but i didn't want comments like "try something first and then question"

Answer (score 0):

You can write your settings into a different file and load them in via the `dofile ([filename])` method, specifying the path to your file of saved goodies. This option should be used carefully however as it also executes the contents of your file and depending on what functions you have inside, it could harm your computer.

A safer option is put whatever content you have into a .lua file which you can load in with `require (modname)`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Simple table load save functions](https://github.com/robmiracle/Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK).

I copy here the info from github:

> USAGE:
>
> ```
> local loadsave = require("loadsave")
>
> myTable = {} myTable.musicOn = false myTable.soundOn = true
>
> loadsave.saveTable(myTable, "myTable.json") Then to read it back in:
> myTable = loadsave.loadTable("myTable.json")
> ```
>
> This basic code, by default, uses system.DocumentsDirectory to save
>   game settings. If you need to save files to other locations, you can
>   pass another argument "CachesDirectory" or "TemporaryDirectory" to the
>   function to apply the change to the specified location.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> loadsave.saveTable(myTable, "myTable.json", system.TemporaryDirectory)
> loadsave.loadTable("myTable.json", system.TemporaryDirectory)
> ```
>
> If you'd like to change the default directory, then you can change the
>   variable in the code (`DefaultLocation = system.TemporaryDirectory`) or
>   call `loadsave.changeDefault(system.TemporaryDirectory)` within your
>   code.

I use that in my application and it works really well. I hope that help you.